# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I need your help. I have a problem that I can't solve.
I am new to this.
I'm trying to send information to the backend. As a result, I get an error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')`.
I want to ask, what is my mistake and is it correct that I am executing a POST request? Thank you

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export let Form_Post = () => {
  let [name, setName] = useState('');
  let [price, setPrice] = useState('');
  let [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  let submitName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  let submitPrice = (e) => {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
  };

  let submitDescription = (e) => {
    setDescription(e.target.value);
  };

  let sendLaptop = (event) => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8081/laptop', {
      name: name,
      price: price,
      description: description,
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    setName('');
    setPrice('');
    setDescription('');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    sendLaptop();
  }, []);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={sendLaptop}>
      <input type="text" value={name} onChange={submitName} />
      <input type="text" value={price} onChange={submitPrice} />
      <input type="text" value={description} onChange={submitDescription} />
      <button onSubmit={sendLaptop}>Send</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `sendLaptop` in your `useEffect` hook as well as on submit. When you do so, there is no event attached, and therefore `event` is undefined so `event.preventDefault` is also undefined.

Comment: On a related note, the `<button>` element does not fire the `submit` event ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is related to `event.preventDefault()` inside `sendLaptop` since it get's called from 2 places (`useEffect` & `onClick` handler).

Where the `sendLaptop` get called from `useEffect`, there is no `event` variable passed.

You should check if event is passed, and only then call it.

```js
let sendLaptop = (event) => {
  axios.post('http://localhost:8081/laptop', {
    name: name,
    price: price,
    description: description,
  });
  if (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  setName('');
  setPrice('');
  setDescription('');
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped.
I apologize for asking, because I'm just learning. 

In the database, before that I already had 4 elements (objects), the last one had id = 4. However, after creating a new object on the frontend, it appears in the database with id = 33.

Please, how could you comment on this, how can this problem be solved? Is this a problem with backend (Spring-boot) or does it already need to be solved in React? Thanks)

Comment: Can you open a new issue fir this?